# I update my Angular 5 to 8 and I got an error on toastr

Tags: angular

I updated my angular 5 to 8

When I start (ng server), I have this error on console

```
Uncaught TypeError: core_1.style is not a function
at Object../node_modules/ng2-toastr/src/toast-container.component.js (toast-container.component.js:118)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
at Object../node_modules/ng2-toastr/src/toast-manager.js (toast-manager.js:4)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
at Object../node_modules/ng2-toastr/ng2-toastr.js (ng2-toastr.js:5)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
at Module../src/app/app.module.ts (app.error-handle.ts:6)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
at Module../src/main.ts (main.ts:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
at Object.0 (main.ts:12)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32)
at main.js:1
```

I already did this commands:

```
npm i ng2
npm i ng2-toastr
```

Angular Version

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It probaly is using `@ViewChild` or `@ContentChild`, these have [breaking changes](https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2019/05/29/what-is-new-angular-8.0/#queries-timing) in Angular 8. Since the package has not been updated for 2 years, you should probaly look for another library.